# Why are WinForms Control.Bottom and Control.Right read only?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I know one can align bottom of a control by manipulating `Control.Top` and `Control.Height`. And similarly `Control.Right`. But why is that .NET decided to not let these properties be modified directly? Its frustrating since last few fays I have been dealing with control positioning.

Comment: In order to truly answer your question, we would have to read the minds of the Microsoft software engineers responsible for this fact; in reality, we can only make educated guesses. Because of that, I think this question is not a very good fit for Stack Overflow's format. Nevertheless, it's an interesting question to think about.

Comment: @stakx if I was very sure that my question was about making guesses, I wouldn't have posted it. I thought there could be some technical/logical complications involved (which I am yet to find in in the answers here).

Comment: You suspect technical/logical complications, but what if there in fact aren't any? I recommend that you re-consider your question: How can we answer your question satisfactorily? Simply arguing why technical complications are *unlikely* (without *proving* it) doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

I believe they have made `Bottom` and `Right` read-only, not because it is technically necessary, but as a way of documenting that it is *these* properties that get re-computed when `Top`/`Height` or `Left`/`Width` are modified.

### **Longer answer:**

There are two property sets: One for absolute coordinates (`Top`, `Bottom`, `Left`, `Right`), and one for dimension (`Height`, `Width`). The relationship between these is defined through the following two invariants:

1. `Width == Right - Left`
2. `Height == Bottom - Top`

Now if, for example, Microsoft decides that the `Top` property should be writable, they need to make one further design decision: Will a change in `Top`...

- affect `Height` and preserve `Bottom`, or
- preserve `Height` and affect `Bottom`?

Unless they introduce a further "anchor" property of some sort that allows the user to choose, Microsoft *must* decide on one of these consequences to guarantee invariant (2) above.

Obviously they decided on the latter of the two alternatives. Next, Microsoft would have needed to document their decision. They could either mention the consequences of adjusting `Top` on their MSDN reference pages... and it turns out they did just that:

> *Changes made to the `Height` and `Top` property values cause the `Bottom` property value of the control to change.* — [Remarks section of the MSDN reference page for the `Control.Top` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top.aspx)

... or they could declare the `Bottom` property as read-only, suggesting to us programmers that this property depends on the other two (`Top` and `Height`)... which they have *also* done:

> *The `Bottom` property is a read-only property. You can manipulate this property value by changing the value of the `Top` or `Height` properties [...]* — [Remarks section of the MSDN reference page for the `Control.Bottom` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bottom.aspx)

So they have documented their (arbitrary) design decision both in English, and additionally through code.

Answer (score 3):

To quote Eric Lippert:
"
You keep on asking "why?" questions, which I find difficult to answer because your question is secretly a "why not?" question. That is, the question you really mean to ask is "I have a notion of how the [feature] obviously ought to have been designed; why is it not like that?"
"

The answer to "why not?" question is probably between:

1. This "feature" (settable Bottom and Right properties) was not
   proposed/was not considered useful
2. The behavior of settable Right
   and Bottom is ambiguous - do I re-size the control in question
   (changing Height/Width) or re-position (changing Top/Right).
   Different people will have different opinions about the "correct"
   behavior here.

Comment: Nope different people cant have different opinion about it since right is synonymous with left and bottom with top! Its only about reposition! If there can occur confusion, then that would have happened with left and top as well which MS decided to forget.

Comment: @nawfal Left and Top origin positioning wasn't invented by Microsoft, it is a legacy from the old CRT scan lines. The graphics drivers needed to know when to start drawing things like windows and components. The Bottom and Right properties are just for convenience and the confusion is verry real. If I change the Width property, then the Right property changes accordingly. So if I change the Right property, why shouldn't the Width change likewise...?

Comment: Ok @JonC I got that now, but I do not find that insight from this answer or your original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Bottom` and `Right` are calculated, manipulating for example Bottom like
`Bottom = 100` would translate to `(Top + Height) = 100`. That action would be ambiguous, did you want to change the height of the control or did you want to relocate it?

Comment: why ambiguous, cant it be just height? Even `Top` can be calculated from Bottom and Height. I am just thinking why are two properties not calculated as the other two.

Answer (score 2):

Because the coordinate system is based on top-left orientation. (0,0) is the top left corner of the screen and all location-based measurements are relative to (0,0). When setting the top-left coordinates, it's very clear what you mean: position. Bottom-right coordinates, however, are more murky because they also involve the height and width (as previously noted).

What would happen if you added 5 to the Right property? Would the location change, or would the width change? It's not a useful or meaningful feature.

EDIT:

> If left and top is not involved with resizing, then why should bottom and right be?

Because the coordinate system is based on top-left orientation, not bottom-right. The GDI, or whatever system you are using to draw the control, calculates position based on the universal origin (0,0) and one point on the control which is relative to that origin. Because the universal origin is the top-left corner of the screen, it makes the most sense to use the top-left corner of the control as the point to use for location.

Imagine these two scenarios:

Scenario 1 - the control does not calculate the bottom-right coordinates, it actually stores those coordinates. The GDI is ready to draw the control. The top-left coordinates are set to (10,10), the height is 10, the width is 10 and the bottom-right coordinates are (25,25). How should the control be drawn?

Scenario 2 - rather than calculating the bottom-right coordinates, the height and width are calculated. The top-left is set to (20,20) and the bottom-right is set to (10,10). How should the control be drawn?

By limiting the programmer to top-left and height/width, the above scenarios will never occur, saving processing time and accidental errors.

Comment: I understand your point about top-left orientation, but to say right and bottom involves height and width is not right. its never about height and width or resizing. Its only about positioning. Which is left and top. If left and top is not involved with resizing, then why should bottom and right be?

Comment: The answer to that last question was too long, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Right` is determined by `Left+Width`, and `Bottom` is determined by `Top+Height`.

You can use `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, and `Height` to position controls just as effectively.

The properties could theoretically be settable, but I guess they thought it might cause too many problems to do so.

Because the underlying architechture does not support `Right` and `Bottom`, it was probably too convenient to just make them calculated properties.

OK, I confess, I'm guessing. There is no clear reason that I can see. You might need to get in contact with the .NET dev team about that.

Comment: I know how to do. I am asking why has MS not left bottom and right property similarly as left and top property..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size or position of a `Control`, you can change the [Control.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) and [Control.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx) properties. I believe that the `Control.Bottom` and `Control.Right` properties are computed from these other properties.

Comment: I know how to do. I am asking why has MS not left bottom and right property similarly as left and top property. In other words if bottom and right properties are computed from other properties, why cant even left and top properties be computed from bottom and right properties?